# Notification shows when it's not supposed to

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently working on a notification that has to show at a specific time chosen by the user.

BUT when I run it, notifications show but not at the selected time, only when I ask the time in a timepickerdialog appear, before even choosing a time.

Does anyone know how to change the code so that notifications only appear at the time selected?

```
showDialog(DIALOG_ID);  //this is the dialog that asks for an hour and minute.


alarmMethod1();


private void alarmMethod1(){


       Calendar calendari1 = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendari1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour_x);
       calendari1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute_x);
       calendari1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

       Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, NotifyService1.class);
       AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(Main2Activity.this, 0, myIntent1, 0);
       alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendari1.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent1);

}
```

Then here is the class where the intent goes:

```
public class NotifyService1 extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    NotificationManager nNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),Main3Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

    Notification mNotify = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Hora d'entrenar!")
            .setContentText("Clica per començar entrenament de pit i braços")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logofinal)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSound(sound)
            .build();

    nNM.notify(1,mNotify);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android API 19, all alarms are inexact in order to reduce battery consumption, that means that your alarms will not be triggered exactly when you want, but if you really need to do it, you need to use setExact and then write the repeat alarm handler by yourself, there's no longer a "set exact and repeat". Please, see:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))